# Jinja Error Return About For Loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have been trying to read text files with Flask and Jinja but using for loops, I have been running into trouble. My code is below:

```
{% for fileNamesIterator in fileNames
fileNameOpen = open(fileNamesIterator, "r")
fileLines = fileName.readlines() %}

<div id="{{ fileNamesIterator[:len(fileNamesIterator)-4] }}" class="title">Title: {{ fileLines[2] }}</div>
<div class="author">Author: {{ fileLines[1] }}</div>
<div class="date">Date Posted: {{ fileLines[0] }}</div>
<br><br>
<div class="mainText"> {{ fileLines[3] }} <br> {{ fileLines[4] }}
</div>
<hr>

{% fileLines.close()
endfor %}
```

The only problem is that it is returning an error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'fileLines'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

I found that it is this causing the problem:

> fileNameOpen = open(fileNamesIterator, "r") 
>  fileLines = fileName.readlines()

But shouldn't I be able to do other python statements after `for` statement but before the `endfor` statement?

Any ideas?

**Solution:** *Jinja* is not *Python* and most of the work needs to be done out of the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja is *not* Python (if you need to be able to write arbitrary Python in your templates you will do better with [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org)).  Instead, you need to do the work in Python and pass the results to Jinja:

```
data = []
for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        file_lines = f.readlines()
        data.append({
            "id": file_name[:len(file_name) - 4],
            "title": file_lines[2],
            "author": file_lines[1],
            "date": file_lines[0],
            "content": file_lines[3:5]
        })

return render_template("template.html", articles=data)
```

Then your template can just be:

```
{% for article in articles %}
<div id="{{ article.id }}" class="title">Title: {{ article.title }}</div>
<div class="author">Author: {{ article.author }}</div>
<div class="date">Date Posted: {{ article.date }}</div>
<br><br>
<div class="mainText"> {{ article.content[0] }} <br> {{ article.content[1] }}
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```